# Aerial Navy Doctrine-Steampunk era like world war 2 with magic. What tactics that can evolve from it?

Tags: science-based, magic, warfare, science-fiction

ok so we have a world with an Aerial Navy with magic included.

I mean Aerial battleships, Airborne Aircraft Carriers and all other sort of ships we can imagine flying in the air, mobile battle fortresses, Floating islands, Rocket planes, flying magicians with Wings.

**Situation**

The situation is that The whole world will be at war and those 10 nations are the primary participants on it with an emerging threat that is a kaijuu that will escalate into world crisis threat(This Kaijuu will be ignored in favor of the ongoing war, but the nations will keep it in mind but it will be a bit too late too react as they will face it as an world crisis level kaijuu that is almost immune to sorcery based and magic based attacks this includes strategic weapons) devastating south africa, middle east, south western Russia, western china and India. Gods won't interfere with the Kaijuu threat but they will provide information on its movement.

**Objective**

What Aerial navy tactics that can be developed and used that is analogous military doctrine from our world in the scenario stated above.

**Nations in comparison**

1. USA (Before World War 1)
2. UK
3. Germany (Before its defeat in world war 1)
4. Imperial Japan
5. China
6. Russia(Before the Red October Revolution)
7. Austria (Before its defeat in world war 1)
8. Italy
9. Australia
10. Canada

NOTE: Don't assume that they have the same size military assets. Just assume their military doctrine.

Resources

Unobtanium - Integral part of the economy and integral part of thrustless propulsion and levitation. Abundant in nature and can be renewed by rerefining and adding a rare phlebotonium that is manufactured by alchemists. Used for power plants.

Oil - Integral part of daily lives of ordinary people as it runs vehicles(Air, Land and sea).

Magic/Sorcery/alchemy - Integral part of the world since the beginning of history. Most consider military magicians/alchemist as weapons first and human secondly but given a lot of privileges and payed handsomely for the lowest position available.

**World Rules**

Thrustless propulsion and Levitation is a norm and preferred way of moving ships and other manmade floating structures. Propeller and rocket are used normally for vehicles. No jet propulsion!

Thrustless levitation and propulsion are limited only to large structures and ships due to machinery size and fuel weight.

Standard piston engines are provided for warplanes and other planes.  Fuel for this engines are exported from middle east, China, USA and Russia

No guided weapons, No nuclear weapons, no cloning technology but has advanced alchemical expertise no philosopher stones! Of course we have homunculus!

Magicians are used mainly for tactical reasons as there are few magicians in military. Most are in academic research, medicine, alchemy and agriculture. A single magician can decimate a city block or a battalion. Almost immune to small arms fire including high powered magic augmented sniper rifle, CQC is the recommended way or capital ship weaponry or another magician. This is due to magic Null Kinetics. China has the most magicians in their military but considered lower quality compared to others.

The difference between magician and sorcerer is that a magicians magic can be replicated by science, sorcery on the other hand can't be replicated.

Sorcery is unique to each person, no same sorcery can exists simultaneously but they can reemerge. 20 sorcerers currently exists. Most of it belongs to Russia, Germany and UK. only 5 of them are strategic though, 2 belongs to USA(Through intense research and development) and 3 belongs to Japan(Due to finely cultured tradition of arrange marriage between strong and useful magical blood lines)

The only strategic deterrent are magicians/sorcerers who are capable of unleashing tantamount amount of damage to the enemy in a single instance. Strategic Magicians and Sorcerers can only be used once since they'll die using their magic/sorcery by being unable to escape the area of effect since satellite targeting or any trans horizon targeting is impossible due to magical phenomenon disturbance in magic oriented devices when performing strategic magic. There are 30 Strategic magicians/sorcerers at the current era. UK has the most strategic deterrent at 7 magicians. But the strongest ones belong from USA, Austria, France, Russia and Japan.

Warplanes are  primary targets of Magicians assigned to defend capital ships and is a proven counter against whole air wings where a single magician can clear the skies. This is negated by rocket planes who can evade their attack with pure speed and armed with anti capital ship weapons with the consequences of being hard to turn and flying one in a battlefield is guaranteed suicide mission or being POW due to it being only able to fly for 10 mins at most.

The wet navy is mostly consists of small ships(Corvette to light cruisers) and submarines. Most notable Wet Navy is from Germany which consists mostly of u-boats used for reconnaissance.

Gods of this world likes to inter act with the mortals through seers or descending themselves but doesn't care about their warfare. They'll interfere if their base of faith are endangered though. Kaijuus evade their base of faith.

Kaijuus(Giant Monsters) are a norm and Battle Groups and squads of magician are needed to subdue them at a minimum level or multinational fleets are needed if it escalates. They escalate from tactical threat into a legit international or world level threat/crisis if not subdued immediately. IJA has a nick name Kaijuu Defense force as  Japan is mostly attacked and killed most Kaijuus, no other nation can top that.

What kind of tactics  would their military do under similar nations or analogous from our world

TL;DR

What tactics will an Aerial Navy used in conjunction with magic as a tactical and strategic resourc and how will they act during a world war and a world crisis level giant monster?

Comment: This seems kind of broad... But otherwise it's a cool idea.

Comment: @AarthewIII its still too broad? I know i ask alot of details but its quietly narrowed down

Comment: well, you are looking for strategy, culture, tactics, etc... I feel like there are way too many good answers for this.

Comment: @AarthewIII i see.. will edit it to narrow it down further can you suggest on how to narrow it down further?

Comment: maybe you could split it into several questions. IE how would aerial navies effect strategies in a post WWI world? And then have another one on on culture.

Comment: "World war 1 or 2" is also incredibly broad. Those two wars were extremely different, tactics-wise, due to technological developments between the two wars and what we learned about tactics with respect to modern technology between the wars. If airship technology/magic has been around for a while, that will probably also change how ground technology has developed, as well as tactics.

Comment: [(Im)Practical flying battleship combat is covered over here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36946/flying-battleship-armored-airship-combat/37000#37000), though without so much magic piled on top. The basic answer still applies: battleships were already obsolete, flying battleships even more so.

Comment: Asking multiple questions in one is not recommended as it makes it hard to answer with a concise and focused reply. Additionally it becomes much harder to rate answers as to whether one is better than another as the "best" answer to each part of your question may be held in different answers. See [tips on how to fix the problem](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3364).

Comment: @Tim B sorry I was unclear. What I meant to say was that he should open another question on culture. And keep this one on strategy.

Comment: @Schwern if a single aircraft carrier attack a single battleship. it is guaranteed to lose all its air wings while being able to do negligible damage to the battleship due to involvement of magicians who can shoot anything they see with impunity and accuracy. Needless to say apart from AA aircrafts need to be wary of magicians who are very accurate with their fire and forget magic apart also with their limited fuel

Comment: I suggest you begin with a question about tactics. From that, move to another question about strategy. From that, you can begin to open out questions about cultural influence. The point is to draw a link to something like the way atomic weapons (tactics) generated a new style of warfare (Cold War, mutually-assured-destruction, etc.), which created a new set of cultural situations.

Comment: @AarthewIII Yeah for common cases like questions that need splitting up we've tried to put together some "canned comments" and descriptions on what to do, follow the link to see :)

Comment: Your question is becoming less clear. You even contradict yourself in the numbers of sorcerers. I'd recomment to clean that up. You can add sections, etc. And adding a TL;DR notice would help clarify what is the intention.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin done... so how can it be put outside of on hold status?

Comment: @micovillena Editing a post which is on-hold automatically place it in the reopen queue. So people will be evaluating it. It currently has one reopen vote. If it gets to 5 (same as for closing), it will be reopened. Theoretically, a moderator can do it alone, but the use around it is not to do it.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin thx! can you take a look at the OP to see if its enough.. i'll post a different one for grand strategies that they will employ

Comment: I don't want to live in a world where Liechtenstein is at war.